# How do I remove a Null exception on a themed map and is it worth it?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I have a map app that uses google_map_flutter package and displays a full screen themed map. My confusion is that when I build the app I receive an unhandled exception for setMapStyle, even though the map displays with the theme.

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setMapStyle' was
>   called on null. E/flutter (30877): Receiver: null E/flutter (30877):
>   Tried calling: setMapStyle("[\r\n    {\r\n        \"featureType\":
>   \"landscape\",\r\n        \"elementType\": \"geometry\",\r\n.......

The theme is a json file that I load using the code in my initState below.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Show the campus Map
    getSunData();
    // _showCampusMap();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    // Check location permission has been granted

    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup
            .locationWhenInUse) //check permission returns a Future
        .then(_updateStatus); // handling in callback to prevent blocking UI

    rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/themes/map/day/simple_bright.json')
        .then((string) {
      mapStyle = string;
    });

    getUserLocation();
  }
```

My method for setting the style is here.

```
// method that is called on map creation and takes a MapController as a parameter
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup
            .locationWhenInUse) //check permission returns a Future
        .then(_updateStatus); // handling in callback to prevent blocking UI

    controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
  }
```

Here is my GoogleMap code

```
_userLocation == null
                  ? Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircularProgressIndicator(
                            backgroundColor: Theme.UniColour.primary[900],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          Text("Retrieving your location..."),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : GoogleMap(
                      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                      initialCameraPosition: // required parameter that sets the starting camera position. Camera position describes which part of the world you want the map to point at.
                          CameraPosition(
                              target: _userLocation,
                              zoom: _defaultZoom,
                              tilt: _tiltAngle), //LatLng(53.467125, -2.233966)
                      scrollGesturesEnabled: _scrollGesturesEnabled,
                      tiltGesturesEnabled: _tiltGesturesEnabled,
                      compassEnabled: _compassEnabled,
                      rotateGesturesEnabled: _rotateGesturesEnabled,
                      myLocationEnabled: _myLocationEnabled,
                      buildingsEnabled: _buildingsEnabled, // not added to db
                      indoorViewEnabled: _indoorViewEnabled, // not added to db
                      mapToolbarEnabled: _mapToolbarEnabled, // not added to db
                      myLocationButtonEnabled:
                          _myLocationButtonEnabled, // not added to db
                      mapType: _currentMapType,
                      zoomGesturesEnabled: _zoomGesturesEnabled,
                      cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds(
                        new LatLngBounds(
                          northeast: uniCampusNE,
                          southwest: uniCampusSW,
                        ),
                      ),
                      minMaxZoomPreference:
                          MinMaxZoomPreference(_minZoom, _maxZoom),
                    ),
```

Any ideas why this exception is occurring, does it need fixing and how would I do that?

[EDIT]

```
void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus status) {
    if (status != _status) {
      // check status has changed
      setState(() {
        _status = status; // update
        _onMapCreated(controller);
      });
    } else {
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        //print("REQUESTING PERMISSION");
        PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
            [PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]).then(_onStatusRequested);
      }
    }
  }
```

> The argument type 'Completer' can't be assigned
>   to the parameter type 'GoogleMapController'.

[/EDIT]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `Completer` class, under your `State` class write the following:

```
 Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
```

Then use the variable `_controller` when calling `setMapStyle`:

```
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup
            .locationWhenInUse) //check permission returns a Future
        .then(_updateStatus); // handling in callback to prevent blocking UI

   _controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter - this then has a knock on effect in my _updateStatus permission.  I tried swapping controller for _controller, but the error remain. Please see my edit above.

Comment: in setState (within the _updateStatus method)

_onMapCreated(controller);

Comment: did you change what you are passing to the method `onMapCreated`?!

Comment: only change the variable here `_controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);`

Comment: No - I kept void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async { the same, added Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer(); and change controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle); to _controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);

Comment: I tried switch what I passed from controller to _controller

Comment: Inside onmapcreatedyou you need to pass a controller of type GoogleMapController

Comment: Hi Peter, I've taken another look at this and I receive an error on setMapStyle in the line -> _controller.setMapStyle(_mapTheme); in my onMapCreated method.

I am passing GoogleMapControler controller to onMapCreated also.

I have noticed this line -> FutureOr<GoogleMapController> get controller => null; which was added by VSCode. I believe this is where the null error is coming from. Using the Completer is simply not working for me. If you have any other ideas, then I would appreciate it. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mark the `Future` methods with `await` for asynchronous processing.

In your `_onMapCreated`, you can add the future method that loads the mapStyle.

```dart
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    final mapStyle = await rootBundle.loadString(
      'assets/themes/map/day/simple_bright.json',
    );

    await controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);

    _updateStatus = await PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(
       PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse
    );
  }
```